# Get Json response in NSURLSessionBackground for NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: objective-c, background, ios7, nsurlsession

I am downloading images,videos with iOS 7 backgroundsession with NSURLSessionDownloadTask and it is working fine.

Now,as Apple doc suggest in background DataTask is not going to work , only Uploadtask and downloadtask are going to work.

So, with this download task i neet to get json data. so i test it with url http://www.abc.com/downloads/weather_sample/test.php?format=json so in this method

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{          
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
    NSDictionary *httpResponse = [response allHeaderFields];
}
```

i am not getting proper response , it is

```
     <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x894de00> { URL: http://www.abc.com/downloads/weather_sample/test.php?format=json } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 734;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 08 Nov 2013 06:42:29 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=2, max=4000";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.3";
} }
```

while i can able to store test.php file in my document directory and then able to parse in json. but for that i have to store that file in my document directory, i am not getting response directly.

Comment: It seems your response is gzip encoded, could that be the problem

Answer (score 1):

URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL tellf you the location that the URLSession stores the downloaded result.

in your case, the result will be a json. You can just open that file and deserialize the nsdata to a nsdictionary